# FOREIGN KEY constraint failed. Django allauth error in EmailAddress

Tags: django, django-allauth

I use allauth in my Django app. I have custom User Model and custom Signup Form. At first, Model and Form were in the app called "main", then I created a new app called "user" and moved them to new app. And now I get FOREIGN KEY constraint failed error when I signup new user.

I have this in my settings.py:

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = "user.Account"
ACCOUNT_FORMS = {
    "signup": "user.forms.CustomSignUpForm",
}
```

**My custom SignUp Form:**

```py
class CustomSignUpForm(SignupForm):
    full_name = forms.CharField(max_length=350, label="Full Name", required=True)
    
    def save(self, request):
        user = super(CustomSignUpForm, self).save(request)
        user.full_name = self.cleaned_data['full_name']
        user.save()
        return user
```

**My models.py:**

```py
class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, email, full_name, password=None):
        if not email:
            raise ValueError("Users must have email address")
        if not full_name:
            raise ValueError("Users must have name")
        
        user = self.model(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            full_name=full_name,
        )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, email, full_name, password):
        user = self.create_user(
            email=self.normalize_email(email),
            password=password,
            full_name=full_name,
        )
        user.is_admin = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    GENDERS = (
        ("M", "Male"),
        ("FM", "Female"),
        ("O", "Other")
    )
    SPECIALIZATIONS = (
        ("DV", "Developer"),
        ("DS", "Designer"),
    )
    email = models.EmailField(verbose_name="email", max_length=60, unique=True) 
    full_name = models.CharField(max_length=350)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=50, choices=GENDERS)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    specialization = models.CharField(max_length=250, choices=SPECIALIZATIONS)


    extra_info = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    contacts = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="date join")
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name="last login")
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superuser= models.BooleanField(default=False)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['full_name']

    objects = AccountManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.email
    
    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return self.is_admin

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return True
```

**Error:**

```
IntegrityError at /accounts/signup/
FOREIGN KEY constraint failed
```

The error came from these pieces of code (allauth source code):

```
... self.user = form.save(self.request)
... user = super(CustomSignUpForm, self).save(request)
... setup_user_email(request, user, [])
... a.save()
```

When I inspect code and local variables near "a.save()" I see this:

```
a: <EmailAddress: emuradyan07@gmail.com>        

addresses, primary = cleanup_email_addresses(
    request, priority_addresses + addresses
)

for a in addresses:
  a.user = user
  a.save()
  EmailAddress.objects.fill_cache_for_user(user, addresses)
...
```

To me it seems that allauth can't create EmailAddress when creating new User.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:

1. Delete migrations and pycache folders from apps
2. Delete database (db.sqlite3)
3. Create db.sqlite3
4. `python manage.py makemigrations user`, where user is app name
5. `python manage.py migrate`